# How to deserialize an array of complex objects with Symfony Serializer?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, xml-deserialization

how can I deserialize this XML

```
<Outer>
   <simpleProperty1>A</simpleProperty1>
   <simpleProperty2>B</simpleProperty2>
   <Inner>
      <simpleProperty3>C</simpleProperty3>
      <simpleProperty4>D</simpleProperty4>
   </Inner>
   <Inner>
      <simpleProperty3>E</simpleProperty3>
      <simpleProperty4>F</simpleProperty4>
   </Inner>
</Outer>
```

into some PHP classes:

```
class Outer 
{
   /** @var string */
   private $simpleProperty1;
   /** @var string */
   private $simpleProperty2;
   /** @var Inner[] */
   private $inners;

   [insert getters and setters here]
}

class Inner 
{
   /** @var string */
   private $simpleProperty3;
   /** @var string */
   private $simpleProperty4;

   [insert getters and setters here]
}
```

using the [Symfony Serializer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)?

The outer object and its simple properties are filled, but instead of the inner object I get an associative array containing two more associative arrays that contain the `simpleProperty3` and `simpleProperty4`.

Comment: You could have a look at [this](http://thomas.jarrand.fr/blog/serialization/) and you probably will need to define a custom denormalizer function. 

You could also look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033732/denormalize-nested-structure-in-objects-with-symfony-2-serializer)

Comment: Can you generate an xml like above with  `Symfony Serializer`? Then you can also `Deserialize` it again. Currently the docu about that, are only with flat/simple objects. You can only go and inject somthing in the getter/setter for INNER and bind the values manualy. But better dig into the llinks that @segFault shows

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I can serialize, but I still cannot deserialize

Comment: Im not really into sympony, but when you can fully serialize it, it must be possible to deserialize it. Seems it is always the same class base. But after having a look into the links from @segFault it seems that complex structures need complex handling/work. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it with a custom PropertyExtractor that points the serializer to the correct type:

```
$encoders = [new XmlEncoder('response', LIBXML_NOERROR)];
$normalizers = [
    new ArrayDenormalizer(),
    new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, 
      new class implements PropertyTypeExtractorInterface
        {
          private $reflectionExtractor;

          public function __construct()
          {
              $this->reflectionExtractor = new ReflectionExtractor();
          }

          public function getTypes($class, $property, array $context = array())
          {
              if (is_a($class, Outer::class, true) && 'Inner' === $property) {
                return [
                  new Type(Type::BUILTIN_TYPE_OBJECT, true, Inner::class . "[]")
                ];
              }
              return $this->reflectionExtractor->getTypes($class, $property, $context);
          }
        })
    ];
$this->serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
```