# deserializing json to embedded object in Symfony 3.2 - Expected argument of type "Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Gps", "array" given

Tags: symfony, serialization

Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Person

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */

class Person
{

/**
 * @MongoDB\bool
 */

private $hasemail;

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Gps")
 */

private $gps;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(name="email", type="collection")
 */

private $email;

}
...
```

Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Gps

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
 */

class Gps
{

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="float")
 */

private $latitude;


/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="float")
 */
private $longitude;

}
...
```

mongo json document

```
{
"hasemail": true,
"gps": {
    "latitude": 42.941579990394,
    "longitude": -85.244641161525
},
"email": [
    "sdfgsdfg@sfgsdfg.org",
    "sdfgsdfg@fgsdfg.com",
    "sdfgsdfg@sdfgsdfg.com"
]
}
```

serializing mongo document to json works perfect. but deserializing json to document throws an error: "Expected argument of type 'Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Gps', 'array' given"

deserialize code:

```
$post = $request->getContent();
$serializer = $this->get('serializer');
$person = $serializer->deserialize($post, Person::class, 'json');
```

Answer (score 5):

so finally I used ReflectionExtractor and it worked like charm. No custom denormalizers necessary.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#recursive-denormalization-and-type-safety

```
    $post = $request->getContent();

    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor()); //

    $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer, new DateTimeNormalizer(\DateTime::ISO8601), new ObjectNormalizer()), [new JsonEncoder()]);


    $person = $serializer->deserialize($post, Person::class, 'json');

    $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
    $dm->persist($person);
    $dm->flush();

    return new Response('Created id ' . $person->getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$post` is likely an array and not a raw JSON object as you're expecting.

```
[{
    key: value
}]
```

is different from..

```
{
    key: value
}
```

Separately, there looks to be a separate issue based on your error message and the example code you have here.

`Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Gps` is the expected class, while deserializing `Voter::class` so you may want to check your namespaces and class names as well.

Comment: post is json object - not an array. class is right - I forgot to rename it here.

Comment: json object or json array will turn in php array anyway. the problem happens after json_decode is trying to turn array into Person::class. deserializer is not working for embed objects or type mismatch ? how to correct ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033732/denormalize-nested-structure-in-objects-with-symfony-2-serializer