# Deserialize json to entity with nested DateTime object in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have an entity which contains a `DateTimeInterface` type field called `completedAt`, and I want to deserialize a JSON object to this entity object.

I tried `DateTimeNormalizer` and `ObjectNormalizer`, but they both gave me an error saying that I can't assign string/array to DateTime object.

For example, I have this entity,

```
class Task
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var DateTimeInterface
     */
    private $completedAt;
}
```

and how I create the JSON object in my test using PHPUnit,

```
$rawData = json_encode([
    'name' => 'test-task',
    'completedAt' => Carbon::now()->toRfc3339String(),
    // I tried some other formats here, such as datetime array, datetime string, etc.
]);
```

In my controller, I tried this (It's a test, not my real code):

```
public function update(Request $request, Task $task, SerializerInterface $serializer): Response
{
    $task = new Task();
    $task->setName('test');
    $task->setCompletedAt(Carbon::now()->toDateTime());

    $json = $serializer->serialize($task, 'json');

    $serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer(), new DateTimeNormalizer()], [new JsonEncoder()]); // array of needed normalizer
    var_dump($serializer->deserialize($json, Task::class, 'json'));
}
```

The I got this error,

> NotNormalizableValueException
>   Expected argument of type "DateTimeInterface", "string" given at property path "completedAt".

How can I deserialize that JSON object by using multiple normalizers?

Comment: Could you show us the JSON payload you're sending?

Comment: @thomas.drbg Updated the description. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer under this question: [deserializing json to embedded object in Symfony 3.2 - Expected argument of type "Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Gps", "array" given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444807/deserializing-json-to-embedded-object-in-symfony-3-2-expected-argument-of-type)

By following the Symfony doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#recursive-denormalization-and-type-safety

I found I didn't install this package: symfony/property-info

Answer (score 1):

If you want your json data to be transformed to an entity you create and you use the symfony serialzer

```
$serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()]); // array of needed normalizer
$serializer->denormalise($json_data,YourEntity::class);
```

should work just fine

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Comment: Tried your method directly from my controller, but it still gives me this error: Expected argument of type "DateTimeInterface", "string" given at property path "completedAt".

Comment: Can we have a look a your controller ?

Comment: I found the reason! I don't have this package: symfony/property-info. Thanks for the help man.