# Symfony Serializer won't work with validation over Annotations

Tags: php, symfony, php-7

I got a problem with the Serializer in combination with validation over Annotations.
I got a json like this:

```
{
   "name": "A name",
   "company": {
     "name": "A company name"
 }
}
```

And my DTO:

```php
class DTO {
    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @Assert\NotNull
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @var Company
    *
    * @Assert\NotNull
    */
    private $company;

    public function getName(): string {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getCompany(): Company {
        return $this->company;
    }

    public function setCompany(Company $company) {
        $this->company = $company;
    }
}

// deserialization in controller
$data = $request->request->all();
$serializer->deserialize($data, DTO::class, 'json');
```

After deserialization I get an Object of `DTO` with property `name` set correctly but `company` is an `array` and not an object of `Company`. If I remove the validation over Annotations deserialization is done correctly.

Docs:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-an-object

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Recursive Denormalization](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#recursive-denormalization-and-type-safety) section in the docs:

> When using the Symfony Standard Edition, all normalizers are automatically configured to use the registered extractors. When using the component standalone, an implementation of `PropertyTypeExtractorInterface`, (usually an instance of `PropertyInfoExtractor`) must be passed as the 4th parameter of the `ObjectNormalizer`.

Therefore, this should work automatically if you are using the standard edition, so I'm assuming you're using the serializer as a standalone. In this case, you can denormalize it like so:

```php
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Extractor\ReflectionExtractor;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor());
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizer);

$data = $request->request->all();
$dto = $serializer->deserialize($data, DTO::class, 'json');
```

If you are using a version below 3.0: [Denormalize nested structure in objects with symfony 2 serializer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033732/denormalize-nested-structure-in-objects-with-symfony-2-serializer)

Comment: I was using the standard edition indeed. I assume the problem was that I provided default values for some of my attributes of the DTO. As soon as I removed these, deserialization worked fine.