# Symfony SerializedName equivalent for collection attributes while denormalizing

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, symfony4

I am having a json request

```
{
   applicant_info:{
      "email": "jhon.doe@gmail.com",
      "given_name": "jhon",
      "family_name": "doe"
   },
   productId: 12
}
```

Having a dto class as below:

```
class Dto
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @SerializedName("product_id")
     */
    public $productId;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @SerializedName("applicant_info")
     */
    public $applicantInfo = [
        'email',
        'givenName',
        'familyName'
    ];
}
```

Now when I use below to deserialize I am not sure how to convert **given_name** and **family_name** from request to 
**givenName** and **familyName** like I have converted **product_id** and **applicant_info** to **productId** and **applicantInfo** using **@SerializedName**

```
$serializer->deserialize(
            $request->getContent(),
            Dto::class,
            self::FORMAT_JSON
        );
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778907/symfony-deserialize-nested-objects