# How do I deserialize a JSON object - which has a nested property - to a Symfony entity?

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization

I’m deserialising JSON to a php class (a Symfony entity) and it’s working fine, but I have a nested property in my JSON which I can’t figure out how to get into the php class.

PHP class:

```php
class Vehicle
{
    private $make:

    /**
     * @SerializedName("meta")
     */
    private $colour;

    // with getters and setters...
}
```

```php
// These 2 lines let us use the @SerializedName annotation
$metadataAwareNameConverter = new MetadataAwareNameConverter($classMetadataFactory);
$objectNormalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, $metadataAwareNameConverter);

$encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
$normalizers = [$objectNormalizer];
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

$json = '
    {
        "make": "VW Golf",
        "meta": {
            "colour": "red"
        }
    }
';
$carJson = json_encode($json);

$vehicle = $serializer->deserialize(
    $carJson,
    Vehicle::class,
    'json',
);

$vehicle->getMake(); // VW Golf
$vehicle->getColour(); // ['meta' => ['colour' => 'red']]
```

…but that last line should return just `red`.

I was hoping that I could do something like `@SerializedName("meta.colour")` or `@SerializedName("[meta][colour]")` or `@SerializedName("meta[colour]")` but each of those resolve to null.

The [Symfony docs on serialization](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) doesn't look like it handles this (simple) case.

[This Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40038650/339213) also deals with nested properties, but in their example the nested property must be deserialised to another php class, not mapped to the existing php class, so that doesn't help me.

How can I get `$colour` equal to `red` when deserializing the JSON?

Comment: Custom normalizer may help you. https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html

Comment: As previous comment said, did you check a custom normalizer with only a custom deserialize function in your case?

Comment: Thanks - you're both right, the custom normalizer is the correct approach. I found the examples in the Symfony docs unhelpful in this regard, I might open a PR to add this to the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom normalizer does the trick. Code follows.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Serializer\Denormalizer;

use App\Entity\Vehicle;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\CacheableSupportsMethodInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ContextAwareDenormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

class VehicleDenormalizer implements CacheableSupportsMethodInterface, ContextAwareDenormalizerInterface
{
    protected ObjectNormalizer $normalizer;
    protected PropertyAccessor $propertyAccessor;

    public function __construct(ObjectNormalizer $normalizer)
    {
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
        $this->propertyAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
    }

    public function denormalize($data, $type, $format = null, array $context = []): Vehicle
    {
        /** @var Vehicle */
        $vehicle = $this->normalizer->denormalize($data, $type, $format, $context);

        // It's possible to directly access the values, but that requires error
        // checking. This method will return a null if it doesn't exist.
        $colour = $this->propertyAccessor->getValue($data, '[meta][colour]');
        $vehicle->setColour($colour);

        return $vehicle;
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return Vehicle::class == $type;
    }

    public function hasCacheableSupportsMethod(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

To use this denormalizer, you can either inject the `SerializerInterface` or explicitly create the serializer (code follows).

```php
$json = '
    {
        "make": "VW Golf",
        "meta": {
            "colour": "red"
        }
    }
';
$carJson = json_encode($json);

// These 2 lines let us use the @SerializedName annotation
$metadataAwareNameConverter = new MetadataAwareNameConverter($classMetadataFactory);
$objectNormalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, $metadataAwareNameConverter);

$normalizers = [new VehicleDenormalizer($objectNormalizer)];
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers);

/** @var Vehicle */
$vehicle = $serializer->denormalize(
    $carJson,
    Vehicle::class,
);

$vehicle->getMake(); // VW Golf
$vehicle->getColour(); // red
```

I'm explicitly creating the serializer because for some reason when the source data was a string and the destination was an integer, the injection method does *not* automatically convert the types and I get the following error:

```
The type of the "VehicleNo" attribute for class "App\Entity\Vehicle" must be one of "int" ("string" given).
```

(This code example isn't using `VehicleNo` as I've simplified it, but included it here to show an example of an error message where, say, `Vehicle` has a property `$vehicleNo` of type `int`).